# trying to encrypt decrypt with given public/private key in java RSA PKCS1

Tags: java, encryption

Im trying to decrypt with giving cypher and given keys. the output is not the same as the given input message.

the given message from external party is url encoded, base64 encoded and encrypted using RSA PKCS1 (from php, code is available)

code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestTut2 {
    @Test
    public void TestKeyPair() throws IOException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        String privateKeyString = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + "MIICXQIBAAKBgQDKQtJAyCu5FHwDncK2LB/J5ClJhulGggyc7vwtji6TJHtSJfgD\n" + "4TLpHRIHh/cHqf3brhpQtYB9yjKlwogji/OzedY2mdTdSOP8O6suJYu3QENN2xG/\n" + "HvT8UiYK3feVLbJtukhJm7eSuwfMDsjHh4AK7g11fVs6EmY+foh3mjoKLQIDAQAB\n" + "AoGAR8N/wDaFtOx8t/fAv0xWlxaaQ5lXqYm5GfF9jlhVVCXsj5AjOJUtsCJ9ZCis\n" + "0I5TIR/b/Gj5xyf34nJsRViBxbnf6XdLGyXmzsNxWZoWbM70JaqU3iQKm605/EnD\n" + "vPgrI0AMfc/h6Kog0zLrKWKkna+wE5839yMmm7WPqgvxSc0CQQDoud5e3yZu/1e+\n" + "7piFZZl6StAecl+k10Wq5kzJeVQRffDB3JCca65H/W1EZIzEh76pUNr7SYAIIcbK\n" + "jzOdbj1vAkEA3n0AudM3mBzklLEUSHs1ZSqFkUMNP9MNIikwkZ/9Z2AlhW5gnwiv\n" + "dgeXonTqlTFux4e7uyKZoJpJcKAgmMicIwJBAIMl206TalE6y/Po+UKTUr470rSV\n" + "t5hpR/Va+wK+wMVqt3ZIGaZMeFZRVnYoQ7us06EO05iwftoWTrRvpqKdMTkCQBkE\n"
                + "QzWhy0l+TjFt69Luj6Vtb5FS0cWQbJSfvwdQzwR1qiJjs9eN+XSzC9jHfq0B3uvu\n" + "lixHirClSIayapfjTrMCQQCM8d97py4u9hCdCpsHBDt54dXkHsDA2abNzaPri/YA\n" + "pNFZGrfXKVGSLFOfsuf7Wj+yL7ew6ZVKOMYdJ+zb9Wwv\n" + "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"; // 128
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    // bit
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    // key
        String publicKeyString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDKQtJAyCu5FHwDncK2LB/J5ClJ\n" + "hulGggyc7vwtji6TJHtSJfgD4TLpHRIHh/cHqf3brhpQtYB9yjKlwogji/OzedY2\n" + "mdTdSOP8O6suJYu3QENN2xG/HvT8UiYK3feVLbJtukhJm7eSuwfMDsjHh4AK7g11\n" + "fVs6EmY+foh3mjoKLQIDAQAB\n" + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        String message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        String cypherText = "EqVFWCMJ2rSy1J0PjAkRRZKkQ24TJ7xQi%2FjKUa3E7ZJ%2FlwtFsBkUDqJ9VUb0aC53O4TM4uNKMmYQNFDTHpQSgoun95ExgoCAvC1BXz2jVzWkKavt1vWbhS1C5VKcWU0hfUOmxZgiOT4rGWpEXVXoLodKLiJnbkvVNZyjgw0LZPQ%3D";

        System.out.println("private:");

        Reader privateKeyReader = new StringReader(privateKeyString);

        PEMParser privatePemParser = new PEMParser(privateKeyReader);
        Object privateObject = privatePemParser.readObject();
        System.out.println("private: " + privateObject.getClass());
        if (privateObject instanceof PEMKeyPair) {
            PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = (PEMKeyPair) privateObject;
            System.out.println("private: " + pemKeyPair.getPrivateKeyInfo());
            System.out.println("public: " + pemKeyPair.getPublicKeyInfo());

            JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");

            PublicKey publicKey = converter.getPublicKey(pemKeyPair.getPublicKeyInfo());

            String encodedURL = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("encrypting using WP publicKey and own cypherText\r\n");

                byte[] encripted = encrypt(publicKey, message);
                System.out.println("encrypted: " + new String(encripted));

                byte[] encodedURLBase64 = Base64.encode(encripted);
                System.out.println("base64: " + new String(encodedURLBase64));

                encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(new String(encodedURLBase64));
                System.out.println("encodedURL: " + encodedURL);
            } catch (Exception erm) {
                System.out.println("erm: "+erm.getMessage());
            }
            // and back
            try {
                System.out.println("decrypting using WP publicKey and own cypherText\r\n");
                String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(encodedURL);
                System.out.println("decodedURL: " + decodedURL);

                byte[] decodedURLBase64 = Base64.decode(decodedURL);
                System.out.println("decodedURLBase64: " + new String(decodedURLBase64));

                String decrypted = decrypt(publicKey, decodedURLBase64);
                System.out.println("decrypted: " + new String(decrypted));
            } catch (Exception erm) {
                System.out.println("erm: "+erm.getMessage());
            }
            // using stuff from external party
            try {
                System.out.println("decrypting using WP publicKey and WP cypherText\r\n");

                String decodedURLWP = URLDecoder.decode(cypherText);
                System.out.println("decodedURLBase64WP: " + decodedURLWP);

                byte[] decodedURLBase64WP = Base64.decode(decodedURLWP);
                System.out.println("decodedURLBase64WP: " + new String(decodedURLBase64WP));

                String decryptedWP = decrypt(publicKey, decodedURLBase64WP);
                System.out.println("decryptedWP: " + new String(decryptedWP));
            } catch (Exception erm) {
                System.out.println("erm: "+erm.getMessage());
            }

        }
        privatePemParser.close();

        System.out.println("public:");
        Reader publicKeyReader = new StringReader(publicKeyString);
        PEMParser publicPemParser = new PEMParser(publicKeyReader);

        Object publicObject = publicPemParser.readObject();
        System.out.println("public: " + publicObject.getClass());
        if (publicObject instanceof SubjectPublicKeyInfo) {
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicSubjectPublicKeyInfo = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) publicObject;
            // System.out.println("private: "+publicSubjectPublicKeyInfo);
            System.out.println("public: " + publicSubjectPublicKeyInfo);

        }
        publicPemParser.close();



    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(Key pubkey, String text) {
        try {
            Cipher rsa;
            rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubkey);
            return rsa.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String decrypt(Key decryptionKey, byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            Cipher rsa;
            rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decryptionKey);
            byte[] utf8 = rsa.doFinal(buffer);
            return new String(utf8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

output code:

```
private:
private: class org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair
private: org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo@251126d8
public: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo@89547063
encrypting using WP publicKey and own cypherText

encrypted: ��m�k�#�:�����1<Y~�*�� !7��6�^
J���)��M'2Ƙ��E�r>��C�����|�$�K��k����6y��[�'�r��[ y~߄nU~��l<�s�9w�a����}�K�
base64: lqptD9Zr7SPjOrKc8MrkCzE8BB9ZAX6CKrGHICE3o/iiNhihXgpKFJ78+ikHst5NJzIfxpjW30XaBnIREj6B7UOkl7me56t8jCSMS/7ua/wVnt74NnmbsFv1J9ly4q/ZWyB5FX7fhBBuVX6F3Ww8x3PXOXeiYbTO8PyKfYZ/S5g=
encodedURL: lqptD9Zr7SPjOrKc8MrkCzE8BB9ZAX6CKrGHICE3o%2FiiNhihXgpKFJ78%2BikHst5NJzIfxpjW30XaBnIREj6B7UOkl7me56t8jCSMS%2F7ua%2FwVnt74NnmbsFv1J9ly4q%2FZWyB5FX7fhBBuVX6F3Ww8x3PXOXeiYbTO8PyKfYZ%2FS5g%3D
decrypting using WP publicKey and own cypherText

decodedURL: lqptD9Zr7SPjOrKc8MrkCzE8BB9ZAX6CKrGHICE3o/iiNhihXgpKFJ78+ikHst5NJzIfxpjW30XaBnIREj6B7UOkl7me56t8jCSMS/7ua/wVnt74NnmbsFv1J9ly4q/ZWyB5FX7fhBBuVX6F3Ww8x3PXOXeiYbTO8PyKfYZ/S5g=
decodedURLBase64: ��m�k�#�:�����1<Y~�*�� !7��6�^
J���)��M'2Ƙ��E�r>��C�����|�$�K��k����6y��[�'�r��[ y~߄nU~��l<�s�9w�a����}�K�
decrypted: ;ܥ�Ǎ1�׳�э�����ň�9���#2�U@�|�����6�\5����C�����9�j]�����tP��dal�v�gђ~��T�!���U�����wĲf���,����R��OX�@�
decrypting using WP publicKey and WP cypherText

decodedURLBase64WP: EqVFWCMJ2rSy1J0PjAkRRZKkQ24TJ7xQi/jKUa3E7ZJ/lwtFsBkUDqJ9VUb0aC53O4TM4uNKMmYQNFDTHpQSgoun95ExgoCAvC1BXz2jVzWkKavt1vWbhS1C5VKcWU0hfUOmxZgiOT4rGWpEXVXoLodKLiJnbkvVNZyjgw0LZPQ=
decodedURLBase64WP: �EX#    ڴ�ԝ�    E��Cn'�P���Q����E��}UF�h.w;����J2f4P�������1����-A_=�W5�)������-B�R�YM!}C�Ř"9>+jD]U�.�J."gnK�5���
d�
decryptedWP: $d0��y�
a5I���Ɖj��7�ۋ킅!�4夣����֔({c���Ba�����;
=�
���jb�P��Hlz�\r��E�m��H��W�N���
�Ɨ����������sH"��
public:
public: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
public: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo@89547063
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to decrypt with the public key. You should be decrypting with the private key:

```
converter.getPrivateKey(pemKeyPair.getPrivateKeyInfo())
```

You may want to help prevent this in future by changing your encrypt method to take a `PublicKey` and your decrypt method a `PrivateKey`.

Fixing this error address your own encrypt/decrypt test. However when you decrypt the data supplied from the third-party, things don't look right:

> decryptedWP: (garbage) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

This might indicate an error in your PHP encryption code.

Your Java code also demonstrates several other errors, including:

- Failing to specify character set when converting from bytes to strings (and vice versa) or when URL encoding
- Failing to completely specify the crypto algorithm. `"RSA"` should be changed to `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"`.
- Pointless use of string constructors: `String foo = new String(otherString)`

Comment: thanks! ive just switched the keys myself and it worked! , see updated code below (maybe for others). ill add you suggestion:D